# How to automatically update/load/refresh view in RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am developing one RCP application to capture and display http requests. The application is like a proxy tool but the functionality is very simple. Till now, I know view change could be triggered by some events: like: selection. But I don't know how to update/load/refresh the view with data changed automatically. In this case, the data should be the captured http requests.

Could you give me some insights? Thanks.

**Updates**
Some nice guys tell us to use observable pattern to do this. The following snippets is my code. But it does not work as expected. The ui cannot be refreshed.

```
IObservableList input = Properties.selfList(Sequence.class).observe(sequences); // Sequence stands for one request, sequences are a list of sequence.

    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ContentProvider());
    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new TableLabelProvider());
    tableViewer.setInput(input);
```

Joseph

Comment: Does you view "just" show the complete HTTP Request as a multi-line text or StyledText, or do you parse the data and show different values in different widgets? E.g. content-type in one Text widget and length in a different Text widget.

Comment: @TonnyMadsen Just show the query strings in http url. The point for this application is not parsing http request/header. It is to show the data in the view when the requests come.

Comment: So with other words, you don't parse the result, but you "just" replace the content of a Text or StyledText widget?

Comment: Right. I want to refresh the view when requests captured. Because one socket start to capture the requests automatically. I need to find one method to do the view refresh.

Comment: See http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/Snippets for some examples on how to do this correctly :-) - especially http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/Snippet009TableViewer.java?view=markup

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the observer pattern. Your data becomes the subject. Every time your data is changed notify your view (observer) to refresh.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 0):

In case you parse the received data, have a look at the Eclipse Databinding framework.

The idea with this framework is that you can bind values from a model representation of the data (usually Bean or EMF) with the various SWT Controls that are used to display the data. The framework will then automatically update the content of the widgets when the model changes (and vise-versa if you let it :-)).

See this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) for an introduction to the framework - you can find plenty of examples and documentation on the web...

EDIT: Also see the [snippets directory](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace_Data_Binding/Snippets) for various solutions to common problems...